# figure out the which parameter produces data type error in python for a given function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

**I am just playing with  Ipython, where i received below error:**

```
In [108]: feed_dict_test = {x:x, y_true:y_true, y_true_cls:data.test.cls}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-2fdafc34bea7> in <module>()
----> 1 feed_dict_test = {x:x, y_true:y_true, y_true_cls:data.test.cls}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

**Question:**

The error says clearly the 'TypeError',  but how can i determine, which parameter out of three produces this error? in this case x?y_true?y_true_cls?

Comment: The keys should be immutable type.

Comment: Whichever of those key objects is an instance of `numpy.ndarray`, or the first one declared if there is more than one.  BTW you are creating a dictionary, not calling a function, although perhaps you want to pass the dictionary as keyword arguments? If so you need to use strings as the keys: `{'x':x, 'y_true': y_true.....}`

Comment: Thanks for reply, and there are three arguments, which argument leads to the error?, any way to figure out from debugging?

Comment: @Whoami: I don't think you can tell from the debug message. You can print out the object types to find the offending object(s), or you can use `isinstance(obj, collections.Hashable)`.

Comment: thank you  @mhawke

Answer (score 3):

One of the keys in your dictionary is of type `'numpy.ndarray'`.
 Dictionaries are defined like this: `{key:value}` so in this example, the keys are: `x`, `y_true` and `y_true_cls`.

In a dictionary, all the keys need to be hashable. `'numpy.ndarray'` is not hashable and so you cannot use it as a key in the dictionary.

To find out the type of an object in python you can use the function `type()`.

```
>>> a = np.zeros((10,10))
>>> type(a)
numpy.ndarray
```

In the dictionary you define, you are using the object `x` as a key to find the object `x`. This could be redundant. Did you mean to write: `{'x':x, 'y_true':y_true, 'y_true_cls':data.test.cls}`?

Comment: An alternative way of defining a dictionary is `dict(x=x, y_true=y_true)`.  Here the key name doesn't have to be quoted. That can be a convenience, but I suspect that in this case it may be source of confusion.  The OP certainly does not mean to save an array to a dictionary using the array itself as the key.